# Show that $(A\Delta B) \cup C = (A\cup C) \Delta (B\setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, propositional-calculus

Show that

$(A\Delta B) \cup C = (A\cup C) \Delta (B\setminus C)$

I want to show it algebraically, but I just can't make it work.

Comment: May I ask how $\Delta$ relates two sets?

Comment: @Khallil this is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference)

Comment: So $A \Delta B = \left( A \setminus B \right) \cup \left( B \setminus A \right) = \left( A \cup B \right) \setminus \left( A \cap B \right)$?

Comment: @Khallil That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A \Delta B )\cup C = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup C
= (A \setminus B) \cup C \cup [(B \setminus A) \setminus C]$$
$$ = [(A \cup C) \setminus (B \setminus C)] \cup [(B \setminus C) \setminus (A \cup C)] = (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C).$$

Comment if you want to have the steps more explained in detail

Answer (score 1):

Define $A\Delta B=(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$.

Write out the LHS explicitly:

$$(A\Delta B) \cup C = (A\cup C) \Delta (B\setminus C)=((A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B))\cup C=(A\cup B \cup C)\setminus (A\cap B)$$

Write out the RHS explicitly:

$$(A\cup C) \Delta (B\setminus C)=((A\cup C) \cup (B\setminus C))\setminus((A\cup C) \cap (B\setminus C))$$
$$=(A \cup C \cup B ) \setminus(A \cap B)$$

They are the same.