# Prove that $(A \Delta B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that: $(A \Delta B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C)$.

It is in a proofs book i'm reading.
I have tried considering arbitrary element, but the logic gets too long and i start getting confused and messy. (Also, the book did not touch logic operations at all).
I have also tried with set operations properties, but i can't see a way using those.

I appreciate hints as much (or more) than complete answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I the think arbitrary element chasing is the easiest and, for me, always easy to follow.  If $x\in (A\Delta B)\cup C$ then either i) $x \in C$ or ii)$x \in A\Delta B$. If $x \in C$ then $x \in A\cup C$ and $x \not \in B\setminus C$ so $x \in (A\cup C)\Delta (B\setminus C)$ and ... so on.... the trick is not to get tripped up in picayune details when broad strokes will do.  ... Okay, to go further if $x\not \in C$ then $x\in A\Delta B$.  So $x \in A$ but $x \not \in B$ .  So $x\in A\cup C$ but as $x\not \in B\setminus C$. So $x \in (A\cup C)\Delta(B\setminus C)$.

Comment: Another trick is to consider the eight partitions of the universe and figure out exactly which partitions these are.  $(A\Delta B)\cup C$ will have $A\cap B \cap C$ will not have $A\cap B\cap C^c$. Will have $A\cap B^c \cap C; A\cap B^c\cap C^c; A^c\cap B\cap C$. Will not have $A^c\cap B\cap C^c$ will have $A^c\cap B^c \cap C$ and will have $A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c$.  You can do similar reasoning and see $(A\cup C)\Delta(B\setminus C)$ will contain and fail to contain the exact same elements.  (This is essentially a proof by Venn Diagram)

Comment: @fleablood why not just answer the question as an answer and not as a comment?

Comment: Just expand both formulae noting that $A \triangle B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)$ and $B \setminus C = B \cap C^c$. The only 'trick' needed is to note (with appropriate substitutions) that $C \cup (D \cap C^c) = C \cup D$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are sets then $(A \Delta B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \Delta (B \setminus C) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709123/prove-that-if-a-b-and-c-are-sets-then-a-delta-b-cup-c-a-cup-c). Also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387757/show-that-a-delta-b-cup-c-a-cup-c-delta-b-setminus-c?rq=1).

Comment: @ennar Because I am trying very hard to not answer questions that others will consider "low quality" questions.  I figure others have asked similar questions

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you. The solution in the first link is similar to the one in the comments. I didn't get it. In the second one there is a proof I understood almost completely, but none of them is as clear to me as the tabular one in this post. That's my argument not to delete this post. But i would understand if it gets deleted. Also, i'm sorry, because i searched for it on google and didn't find those post you commented. I should've searched in this site specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always start making a table of all 8 possibilities (I added extra columns for the sub-expressions to make it easier to fill out):

$$
\begin{array}{|c c c|c c|c c c|}
\in A? & \in B? & \in C? & \in A \triangle B? & \in (A\triangle B) \cup C? & \in A \cup C? & \in B \setminus C? & \in (A \cup C)\triangle(B\setminus C)
\\\text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no}
\\\text{no} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes}
\\\text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes}
\\\text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes}
\\\text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes}
\\\text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes}
\\\text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no}
\\\text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes} & \text{Yes} & \text{no} & \text{Yes}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Why not using pictures?

On the left $A\Delta B \cup \color{red}{C}$ on the right $A\cup C \Delta (\color{red}{B\setminus C})$ where the chequered/grid part must be excluded from the set.
[image]

Comment: Most people don’t consider pictorial arguments valid, re: “Why not use a picture “

Comment: Thank you! It is useful to understand the proposition in an intuitive sense, but i wanted the most structured or strict proof possible.

Comment: I know and somewhat understand, yet I think that writing out a truth table is nothing short of boring.